# C# xceed DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker, xceed

I am using c#, wpf and the xceed toolkit for more advanced items
but now I am struggling to get the value from the picker.

Here is what i did in my xaml:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="fromDTP"/>
```

And here is what I try to do in code-behind to get the date:

```
var datefrom = fromDTP.SelectedDate;
```

But i think this doesn't work because it shows me that the value
is still null...even when i select a date. Am I missing something ?

Comment: What version of xceed toolkit are you using? In community version 2.9.0 there is no `SelectedDate` property, but it has `Value` property which returns nullable `DateTime` ([docs](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SelectedDate property belongs to the WPF DatePicker. NOT to the xceed project.
You should use Value and you can bind it.
See the example below.

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Format="Custom" x:Name="fromDTP"
                FormatString="MM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss tt"
                TimeFormat="Custom"
                TimeFormatString="hh:mm:ss tt"
                Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Value="{Binding Path=CleanLogsDeletionDate, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="30" Width="172" />
```

And the property changed class:

```
public class HelperInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime m_CleanLogsDeletionDate;
    public DateTime CleanLogsDeletionDate
    {
        get
        {
            return m_CleanLogsDeletionDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_CleanLogsDeletionDate != value)
            {
                m_CleanLogsDeletionDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

}
```

}